# errors in the session codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a problem with a session in CodeIgniter, I want to make as a session with token. But there is an error as follows

Fatal error :  `Call to undefined method CI_Session::set_token()`

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('appdata','mod');
    $this->load->library('session');

}   

public function token($id_user)
{
    $token="";
    $date_key = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",time());
    $random_key = rand(1,0);
    $usertoken = substr($id_user,2,4);
    $token = $date_key."-".$usertoken."-".$random_key;
    $this->session->set_token('key_token',$token);
    session_start();
    return $token;
}
```

please help me , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not set_token it's set_userdata

```
public function token($id_user)
{
    $token="";
    $date_key = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",time());
    $random_key = rand(1,0);
    $usertoken = substr($id_user,2,4);
    $token = $date_key."-".$usertoken."-".$random_key;
    $this->session->set_userdata('key_token',$token);
    session_start();
    return $token;
}
```